# Can I get a user's cell tower info via USSD

Tags: node.js, location, triangulation, ussd, trilateration

I would like to know if it is possible to get a user's coordinates or the cell tower data via USSD code calls.

For instance I dial *123# (which is my USSD service code);

Is it possible to get the cell tower information or location coordinates and if so, any leads?

I really appreciate your assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can get cell tower data from a USSD service provider.

The data is bundled up as part of the POST/GET data. You just have to read it.

> In most instances, you have to contact the major network service provider offering them a legitimate reason as to why you seek to use the cell tower info.
>
> This means that it is **most likely** that your current **USSD service provider** *DOES NOT* provide you this information as required by law in most (**if not all**) countries.